# access nested property using bracket notation

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Says I have `var input = {'name':'john'}`

I do 
`input['name'] = 'James'`

it become `var input = {'name':'john'}` but can I pass value with dot to access nested property?

Like

`var input = {"name":"john","grades":"{english:"A","math":"C"}"}`

I can't change the math value by doing `input["grades.math"]`.

Comment: `input["grades"]["math"]`

Comment: No. You can do `input["grades]["math"]"` You can have properties with special characters that cannot be defined using dot notation. So you will have to use bracket notation

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json

Answer (score 23):

You can access that value by these ways:

```js
var input = {"name":"john","grades":{"english":"A","math":"C"}}

console.log(input["grades"]["math"]);
console.log(input.grades.math);
console.log(input["grades"].math);
console.log(input.grades["math"]);
```